# angular JS populate drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate a drop down list with value from my database.  I know the data is being received because I tested my API call.  I am having trouble actually getting it to populate the drop down list.  The drop down list is in a table that when an edit button is clicked, the row can be edited.  Below is my code.

JS file:

```
    $http.get($rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "GetBusNumbers")
      .then(function (result) {
          angular.copy(result.data, _busNumbers);
          deferred.resolve();

    $scope.allBusNumbers = $scope.data.getBusNumbers;
```

HTML:

```
    <td><span editable-select="b.BusNumber" e-name="BusNumber" e-form="formDeviceEdit" ng-options="num.BusNumber for num in allBusNumbers"> {{ b.BusNumber }}</span></td>
```

Comment: is $scope.allBusNumbers being set before the .get returns? what is _busNumbers?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you've provided, `$scope.allBusNumbers` never gets the API results. Is `$scope.data.getBusNumbers` a function that returns the value of `_busNumbers`?

If that is the case, you need to execute that function to return its values when you assign it to `$scope.allBusNumbers`

```js
$scope.allBusNumbers = $scope.data.getBusNumbers();
```

Comment: I just didn't add all my code in.  I know for 100% that allBusNumbers gets the data from the api.  When it outputs though, i displays {{b.BusNumber}} instead of data

Comment: I am assuming this directive is inside of an ng-repeat. Does `b.BusNumber` have any value before the select modifies it? If it doesnt have any value, the select control doesnt have anything to show. Trying changing the display value of your anchor tag to something like `{{ b.BusNumber || 'Select Business Number' }}`